# How to check if a incoming message in Android has the correctly Keyword

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, broadcastreceiver, inbox

I am creating a op-out app. I am using [Incomming SMS Broadcast Receiver](http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87), I need to check if the incoming message contains a specific keyword:

i.e

From: 656565451

msn: I want to **op-out** news

code .i.e - "this does not work"

```
String senderNum = phoneNumber;
String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

//check if user message has this keywork
String keyWord_code = "op-out";


Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("op-out");

if (pattern == keyWord_code ) {
  //Do the op-out function here
}
else {
  //Send message to user 
}
```

Comment: Check if(message.contains(keyWord_code)) { //do the opt-out } else { //send message }

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to use `Regex`?

Well, you can try something a little simpler first before going on to `RegEx`:

```
if( message.contains(keyWord_code) ){
  // do something
}else{
  // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have problems with the receiver or what. If you just want to know if the msg body has the word "op-out" you just need the next code:

```
if(message.contains(keyWord_code) {
//...
} else {
//...
}
```